# How to format date output with spaces as variable in script?

Tags: bash, date

I want to make the `date` command with nice formatting like this:

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2015-09-17 16:51:58
```

But I want to save this in variable, so I could call from script like this:
`echo "$(nice_date) [WARNING] etc etc"`

However it does not work

```
$ nice_date="date +%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
$ echo "$($nice_date)"
date: extra operand ‘%H:%M:%S’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

$ nice_date="date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\""
$ echo "$($nice_date)"
date: extra operand ‘%H:%M:%S"’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

$ nice_date='date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
$ echo "$($nice_date)"
date: extra operand ‘%H:%M:%S"’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

What is correct way to do this, so that date command to get one correct argument?

Comment: As a side note, your date format string can be shortened to `"%F %T"` if you are using GNU `date`.

Comment: The problem's the space.  If you use `nice_date="date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`, it works.  I can't currently see how to get that space protected from the second shell.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason your example fails is because of the way the shell's word splitting works. When you run `"$($nice_date)"`, the shell is executing the `date` command with two arguments, `"+%Y-%m-%d"` and `"%H:%M:%S"`. This fails because the format string for date must be a single argument.

The best way to do this is to use a function instead of storing the command in a variable:

```
format_date() {
  # echo is not needed
  date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "$@"
}
format_date
format_date -d "2015-09-17 16:51:58"
echo "$(format_date) [WARNING] etc etc"
```

If you really wanted to store the command in a variable, you can use an array:

```
nice_date=(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# again echo not needed
"${nice_date[@]}" -d "2015-09-17 16:51:58"
```

For more details on the complex cases of storing a command in a variable, see [BashFAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I'm getting `date: extra operand ‘’` errors with both approaches above

Comment: This is not working ... bash date command is the most confused thing to handle.

Comment: `date: extra operand ‘2015-09-17 16:51:58’
Try 'date --help' for more information.`

Comment: @MaXi32 i've only tested this solution with GNU date. It might not work with other versions such as on osx.

Comment: @jordanm I'm using GNU date in Debian 11.  So, I suggest that you copy paste this command into the distribution and see that if you can reproduce this issue. Similar issue also mentioned by Jeff Puckett. I think the code is not wrong but the GNU date is the most complex thing to handle in script due to incompatibility (like timezone incompatible). This is the reason I hate bash scripting when dealing with date.

Comment: @MaXi32 I was able to reproduce it on my current fedora machine. Updated the answer, the issue was a missing `-d` option for `date`.

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. I was trying to call a script with a single arg like this `dialog.sh "The time is"\`date +'%I:%M %p'\`` but the output of the part inside backticks was not getting enclosed as required. Moving it inside the double quotes solved that.

Answer (score 10):

One easy way is to just to 'escape' the space with a \

```
nice_date="date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the simple answer. This worked for me.

Comment: This should be the top answer - nice and simple

Answer (score 4):

I agree a function is the best way to go.  As an alternative simply store the format as a variable rather than the whole command:

```
$ nice_date='+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
$ echo "$(date "$nice_date") [WARNING] etc etc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortest answer is

```
#if you want to store in a variable
now=$(date '+%F %T');
echo $now

#or direct output
date '+%F %T'
```

Comment: Not sure why you've included double quotes. Just use: `date '+%F %T'`. Note: Without the space, no quotes are required: `date +%F-%T`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```bash
nice_date="date +%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
echo "$($nice_date)"
```

Try:

```bash
nice_date_format="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
echo $(date "$nice_date_format")
```

Also, you don't need the last command substitution:

```bash
date "$nice_date_format"
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try out the below:

You need to add the symbol "`" the symbol that is on the tilde key in the keyboard. The symbol says the shell to execute the command first and then assign to the variable.

```
[root@RHEL01 ~]# My_Var=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
[root@RHEL01 ~]# echo $My_Var
2015-09-17 10:05:30
[root@RHEL01 ~]#
```

Comment: Same problem as Iain's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem; had to put a date into an awk print for processing by splunk. I used

```
DATE1=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

DATE2=`date +%T`
```

then

```
awk ' { print "['$DATE1' '$DATE2'] topic=" $1, etc
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly how this answers the question?